# Failure delivering result ResultInfo to activity : java.lang.NullPointerException: Activity must not be null

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

Hi I was working on an application that authenticate using google but I got an error after running it in the emulator. I don't know what exactly is going on because I pasted documentation's codes without any changes. Here is the error which I've got:

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1302730037, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.platform/com.example.platform.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Activity must not be null
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5392)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5431)
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:67)
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2272)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7902)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:933)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Activity must not be null
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotNull(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.0.0:2)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.LifecycleActivity.(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.0.0:1)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.LifecycleCallback.getFragment(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.0.0:1)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzv.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.addOnCompleteListener(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:3)
at com.example.platform.LoginFragment.firebaseAuthWithGoogle(LoginFragment.kt:92)
at com.example.platform.LoginFragment.onActivityResult(LoginFragment.kt:69)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$7.onActivityResult(FragmentManager.java:2617)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$7.onActivityResult(FragmentManager.java:2597)
at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.doDispatch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:392)
at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.dispatchResult(ActivityResultRegistry.java:351)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onActivityResult(ComponentActivity.java:647)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:140)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8243)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5385)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5431) 
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:67) 
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2272) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7902) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:933)**

and here is my code:

LoginFragment.kt:

```
package com.example.platform

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.platform.databinding.FragmentLoginBinding
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions
import com.firebase.ui.auth.IdpResponse
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider


class LoginFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "LoginFragment"
        const val RC_SIGN_IN = 1001
    }

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentLoginBinding
    private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentLoginBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(requireContext(), gso)
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        binding.google.setOnClickListener {
            signIn()
        }
    }
    private fun signIn() {
        val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
    }
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            val response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data)
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Successfully signed in user.
                try {
                    // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                    val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
                    val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)!!
                    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.id)
                    firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.idToken!!)
                    Log.i(
                        TAG,
                        "Successfully signed in user " +
                                "${FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.displayName}!"
                    )
                } catch (e: ApiException) {
                    // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                    Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e)
                }
            }
            else {
                // Sign in failed. If response is null the user canceled the sign-in flow using
                // the back button. Otherwise check response.getError().getErrorCode() and handle
                // the error.
                Log.i(TAG, "Sign in unsuccessful ${response?.error?.errorCode}")
            }
        }
    }
    private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken: String) {
        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
        activity?.finish()
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(requireActivity().parent) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d("signIn", "signInWithCredential:success")
                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_mainFragment)
                } else {
                    Log.d("signIn", task.exception.toString())
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: try
private fun signIn() {
        val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
        activity?.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
    }

Comment: What is the exact code that produces that error?

Comment: this the exact code and the the exact  line that produces the error is this:
.addOnCompleteListener(requireActivity().parent)